# Disable isc-dhcp-server form startup

Tags: ubuntu, boot, startup

I am working with isc-dhcp-server on Ubuntu 14.04.1, and I don't want that it runs on start-up, so I disabled it from rc with:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f isc-dhcp-server remove
```

but it still runs on start-up.
I looked at `rc.local, .bashrc` and didn't see any call to it.
I tried to check with `sudo sysv-rc-conf` but all run devel for isc-dhcp-server are disable,
What else could I check, to disabled it form start-up.

Comment: Can you rename conf files for the service to something like: `mv isc-dhcpserver.conf isc-dhcp-server.atop` and `mv isc-dhcpserver6.conf isc-dhcp-server6.stop` and see if it works?

Comment: Hello, i did it moving dhcp.conf with: 'sudo mv /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf.stop', but how i move it when i start isc, it doesn't work, so should i create a script or something?, thz

Comment: Oh, if you want to start it it is trying to find *.conf files.

Comment: Hello, my bad, i mean that i want start isc, but because i move it it doesn't start now, should  i create a script that move it again to isc-dhcpserver.conf, and then start it, but then i need use another script to disable it, i think.